# How to allow content security policy to run external javascript from google api?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, content-security-policy

This is my current script-src content security policy for my app:

`script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com;`

trying to load the following external js code:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}&libraries=places&language=he`

using unsafe-inline it works, but probably unsafe, so I want to remove it in my code, but then it doesn't allow the script to run.
tried to add to script-src a value such as https://maps.googleapis.com/* but it still didn't work.
how would one allow scripts from a specific domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but was able to resolve it by using a [hash](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#script-src-hash-usage) with `https://*.googleapis.com` whitelisted.

> The `script-src` directive lets developers whitelist a particular inline
>   script by specifying its hash as an allowed source of script.
>
> Usage is straightforward. The server computes the hash of a particular
>   script block’s contents, and includes the base64 encoding of that
>   value in the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'sha256-...4aQo=' https://*.googleapis.com">
```

Note that for dynamic applications it's better to use a [nonce](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#script-src-nonce-usage).

Hope this helps!