# How to make Google Api Content Security Policy for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, electron

I am trying to use Electron.js to make a small app and am trying to add a Google maps page to it. I have already aquired an API key. When I run the the app it briefly shows an image of Google Maps then pops up the error:"Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."
When I open the console I see the error:

```
"security-warnings.ts:179 Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security
    Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of
    this app to unnecessary security risks.

For more information and help, consult
https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
This warning will not show up
once the app is packaged.
(anonymous) @ security-warnings.ts:179
Promise.then (async)
warnAboutInsecureCSP @ security-warnings.ts:172
logSecurityWarnings @ security-warnings.ts:295
loadHandler @ security-warnings.ts:312
async function (async)
loadHandler @ security-warnings.ts:311
load (async)
securityWarnings @ security-warnings.ts:315
(anonymous) @ init.ts:216
./lib/renderer/init.ts @ init.ts:217
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
NativeModule.compile @ internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:287
NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader @ internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:222
loadNativeModule @ internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:23
Module._load @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module._load @ electron/js2c/asar.js:717
Module.runMain @ internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1038
(anonymous) @ internal/main/run_main_module.js:17
js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:56 Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error
_.od @ js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:56
(anonymous) @ common.js:73
(anonymous) @ common.js:149
c @ common.js:67
(anonymous) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1sfile%3A%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fisaiahbell%2FProjects%2Fgeo-app%2Fmap.html&MY_API_KEY&callback=_xdc_._m2aezz&key=YOUR_API_KEY&token=54562:1"
```

My current Code is as follows:

Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        </head>
      <body>


        <center>
          <a href="map.html">Open Maps</a>
        </center>








         <script src="./render.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>




    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
      </head>
      <body>
```

map.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>



    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Markers</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>



  </head>
  <body>
    <button><a href="index.html">Go Back</a><</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're getting this error:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error

This means that you need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk) the JavaScript API on your project.

If once enabled, you are having CSP related errors that prevent your map from loading, then check out [How to allow content security policy to run external javascript from google api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758547/how-to-allow-content-security-policy-to-run-external-javascript-from-google-api)

Hope this helps!